# error found library not found for -lGoogleAnalytics in xcode 5.0?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I am importing a project from svn and build that project in Xcode 5.0.but I am getting this error:

> library not found for -lGoogleAnalytics

Can you please tell me how to remove this error and is there any sdk missing in my xcode ?

Comment: The error is quite obvious. Did you follow [Google Analytics Getting Started guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/) carefully?

Comment: You just have to add a framework for it and you are good to go.

Comment: Add the framework to build phases and then link its path in the build settings